# How can I check if a string has all different characters?

Tags: c#, string

For example,

true if the string contains one or more repeated characters.

false if the string is composed of all different characters.

```
"A normal string with repeated characters" --> true
"Another" --> false
"abcdefghijklm" --> false
"aa" --> true
```

Comment: Well, I can think of one way off the top of my head using LINQ... but what have you tried so far? What would "Aa" give?

Comment: "Aa" should return false

Comment: Gonza, you seem to have ignored the rest of Jon's comment, what have *you* tried?

Comment: My string is 4 digits. I tried comparing each character but it seemed sketchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of the string as a sequence of characters. A sequence contain at least one duplicate if the count of the *distinct* elements is not equal to the overall count of the elements.

In other words:

```
bool containsDuplicates = str.Distinct().Count() != str.Length;
```

(This will be constructing a `HashSet<char>` behind the scenes, so it's basically equivalent to the answers which construct one explicitly and then use the `Count` property... I just find this approach slightly clearer, personally, with the explicit mention of distinctness.)

Comment: Thanks, this worked!

Answer (score 4):

```
string str = "ab";  //.ToLower() -- maybe
bool ok = str.GroupBy(x => x).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
```